# SwiftUI: (Bool variable in ForEach) What is wrong with my variable in ForEach?

Tags: swift, foreach, swiftui, boolean, show

I want to make 2 bool variables for each string in array using ForEach but the bool variables don't work when I press the button, What can I do?
(with this code I wanna make a button, and when it is pressed, show more info with a transition, I want two variables for each one)

```
ForEach(0 ..< Array.count, id:\.self){ ArrayCount in
                                
                                let Title = Array.count[ArrayCount]
                                let Description = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: Title+"Description") ?? ""
                                
                                var ShowTip = false
                                var PressAnim = false
                                
                                    VStack(alignment: .center){
                                                Button(action:{
                                                    withAnimation {
                                                        ShowTip.toggle()
                                                        PressAnim.toggle()
                                                    }
                                                }){
                                                    ZStack
                                                    {
                                                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                                                            .foregroundColor(.clear)
                                                            .background(Color(UIColor.systemGray4))
                                                            .cornerRadius(20)
                                                            .frame(width: WidthScreen)
                                                            .rotationEffect(.degrees(EditMode ? 2 : 0))
                                                            .animation(self.EditMode ? Animation.easeInOut(duration: 0.1).repeatForever(autoreverses: true).delay(0.1) : Animation.easeInOut(duration: 0))
                                                            .rotationEffect(.degrees(EditMode ? -2 : 0))
                                                            .animation(self.EditMode ? Animation.easeInOut(duration: 0.1).repeatForever(autoreverses: true).delay(0.2) : Animation.easeInOut(duration: 0))
                                                        
                                                        HStack{
                                                        Text(Title)
                                                            .font(.custom("Arial", size: 20))
                                                            .fontWeight(.bold)
                                                            .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.label))
                                                            .frame(width: WidthScreen - 25, height: 50, alignment: .leading)
                                                            .offset(x: 10, y: 0)
                                                        
                                                        Image("Arrow2").resizable()
                                                            .renderingMode(.template)
                                                            .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.label))
                                                            .rotationEffect(.degrees(PressAnim ? 90 : 0))
                                                            .frame(width:10, height: 19)
                                                            .offset(x: -10, y: 0)
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                                .frame(width: WidthScreen, height: 50, alignment: .center)
                                                .fixedSize()
                                            if ShowTip{
                                                
                                                ZStack
                                                {
                                                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15)
                                                        .foregroundColor(.clear)
                                                        .background(Color(UIColor.systemGray4))
                                                        .cornerRadius(15)
                                                        .frame(width: WidthScreen)
                                                    
                                                    HStack{
                                                        Text(Description)
                                                            .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.label))
                                                            .padding(.all, 15)
                                                    }
                                                }
                                                .frame(width: WidthScreen, alignment: .center)
                                                .transition(.asymmetric(insertion: .scale, removal: .opacity))
                                                .fixedSize()
                                                }
                                    }
                            }
```

Comment: try moving your scoped variables (`ShowTip` ..) out of `ForEach`

Answer (score 0):

Move them out of body context and make them state property of your view, like

```
@State private var ShowTip = false
@State private var PressAnim = false
```

**Important:** do name variables lowercased and meaningful, because, for example, your `Array` conflicts with standard swift type `Array`, so consequences might be unpredictable. The same is for your custom types - give them unique names.